# ORDER BY when using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep encountering a syntax error when trying to ORDER BY on a section of dynamic SQL.

I have fairly basic knowledge of SQL but here's what I've tried (I don't want to include entire code), I have correctly declared SQL and DBName at the top, as well as using EXEC at the bottom:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 1
Test_Time,
Test_ID,
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.dbo.Event_Table'
ORDER BY Test_Time DESC
```

I would just like to know if this is possible or whether I need to try another method. The issue is in ORDER BY as code works perfectly without it.

Comment: You have to put ORDER BY inside the sql statement `+'ORDER BY Test_Time DESC'`
and then execute it

Comment: Share the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to inject the database name into the query directly, you can execute `sp_executesql` dynamically instead.. You can just do `DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @proc @SQL;`

Comment: @Charlieface how does that simplify things?

Comment: @Xedni You don't need to inject the database name all over the placem, just once in the procedure name.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Didn't make a lot of sense in this case with one database reference, but I could see it elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` has to be within the `@SQL` text string like so:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 1
Test_Time,
Test_ID,
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.dbo.Event_Table
ORDER BY Test_Time DESC'
```

(I just moved the trailing apostrophe (') from after `Event_Table` down one line to after `DESC`.)